# Operating System Script action type in oracle alerts

Tags: oracle, unix, alerts

Good day

Kindly assist, I have created  a periodic alert using Operating System Script as an action type.

I would like to know how can I achieve the the summary template  functionality used in MESSAGE action type:

```
=**= Enter summary template below this line =**=
**
=**= Enter summary template above this line =**=;
```

Currently if there are three  different employee records then the alert will send three emails for each employee.Instead I would like  all employees to be listed in email.

The operating System Script code is as follows:

```
echo 'Dear Supervisor

Employee Number :   &employee_number
Employee Name   :   &full_name' |mutt -s "Attachment" -a /u01/ProgressReport.doc  &tt
```